# How to call java method on main class

Tags: java, methods

I'm a beginner in Java and I have a very simple problem. I'm trying to finish an activity and I forgot how to call a method on the main class.

I keep getting an error whenever I try ways to call the `computeSum` method on the main class.

```
Error: Error: Main method not found in class array.Array, please define the main method as: public static void main(String[] args)


public class Array{
    public static void main(String[] args ){
        //Dont know what to put here to call computeSum
    }

    public int computeSum(int[] nums){
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<nums.length; i++){
            sum= sum+nums[i];
        }  
        return sum;    
    }
}
```

Comment: You can perhaps google all this stuff.

Comment: "I keep getting an error": *what* error, from what?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose if your class is there in **com.arr** package. you can specify the qualified name of the class at the time of creating object. Because **Array** class is already available in **java.util** package. It is better to create object to **your Array class** along with package name.

```
public static void main(String[] args){

             com.arr.Array a1 = new com.arr.Array();
             int[] numberArray = {1,7,9,0,45,2,89,47,3,-1,90,10,100};
              a1.computeSum(numberArray);
            }
```

`computeSum()` it's an instance method. we have to create Object to your class for calling the instance methods.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
public class Array{
public static void main(String[] args ){
    //Dont know what to put here to call computeSum
    int[] nums = {1,2,3,4,5};        
    int sum=computeSum(nums);
    System.out.println(sum);
}

public static int computeSum(int[] nums){
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<nums.length; i++){
        sum= sum+nums[i];
    }  
    return sum;    
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an instance to invoke member method of a class.

```
public static void main(String[] args ){
    Array myArray = new Array();
    int[] values = new int[] {1,2,3,4};
    myArray.computeSum(values);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to understand the difference between static classes/members and instance classes/members.

Your `main` method is static - as is standard for the entry method of a program - meaning it is available immediately without any binding to an instance of the Array object.

Your `computeSum` method is an instance method. Meaning that you need an instance of the object `Array`, to use it, and it will execute in that object's context.

Your choices:

1)
Make computeSum static:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    computeSum({1,2,3});   // or Array.computeSum() outside of Array
}
public static int computeSum (int[] nums) {
   int sum = 0;
   for (int i=0; i<nums.length; i++){
       sum= sum+nums[i];
   }  
   return sum;    
}
```

2)
Make an instance of the Array object:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Array myArray = new Array();
    myArray().computeSum({1,2,3});
}
public static int computeSum (int[] nums) {
   int sum = 0;
   for (int i=0; i<nums.length; i++){
       sum= sum+nums[i];
   }  
   return sum;    
}
```

Static code - not ran in the context of an object's instance - can not reference members that are not static, this makes sense as, how would it know what object instance of that member you are referencing (`myArray1.computeSum()`? or `myArray2.computeSum()`? It doesn't even know these two instances of the myArray object exist).

Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can read about instance methods and static methods.
`computeSum()` is an instance method, which means it would need an object of Class Array to be called, example:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

     Array array = new Array();
     int[] nums = {1,2,3};
      array.computeSum(nums);
    }
```

Alternatively, you could make it a static method to use it without making an object, which is not recommended, but incase you want, this is how you can do it:

```
public class Array{
public static void main(String[] args ){

      int[] nums = {1,2,3};
      int sum = computeSum(nums);
}

public static int computeSum(int[] nums){
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<nums.length; i++){
        sum= sum+nums[i];
    }  
    return sum;    
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use reflection just for a change ;)

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/

Answer (score 0):

Firstly your method have an attribute which is "int[] nums " to call the method you need to set a value to your attribute . 
NOTE that you don't have to give the same name to your attribute while calling.
for example :   1 - `int[] Myattribute = {1,2,3};
           int sum = computeSum(Myattribute );`

put this line incide your Main it ill work